# Save Outlook attachment using a cell value as the file name

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to save the Outlook attachment from a particular sub folder to a local path.

I'm able to save the file as is to the local path.

The requirement is to save the xl attachment using a cell value of ThisWorkbook as the file name.

```vb
Sub ManualPunchAttachmentsExtract()
    Dim OlFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim OlMail As Object
    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OlItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim Get_namespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets("MP File Save").Activate
    Range("H3").Activate
    
    Set OlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    If err.Number = 429 Then
        Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    
    strFolder = InputBox("Please Enter the Folder Path alongwith ' \ ' at the end", Path)
    
    'Set Get_namespace = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set OlFolder = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("shaikajaz.k@flex.com").Folders("Archive").Folders("Juarez").Folders("Manual Punch")
    Set OlItems = OlFolder.Items
    '.Restrict("[Unread]=true")
    
    For Each OlMail In OlItems
    
        If OlMail.UnRead = False Then
             
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            Sheets("MP File Save").Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = OlMail.Subject
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = OlMail.ReceivedTime
            
            If OlMail.attachments.Count > 0 Then
                For i = 1 To OlMail.attachments.Count
                    OlMail.attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFolder & "\" & OlMail.attachments.Item(i).FileName
                    OlMail.UnRead = False
                    ThisWorkbook.Activate
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Next i
            
            Else
            
            End If
         End If
    Next
MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: There isn't a problem with the code but the requirement is to save the outlook attachment to a local path directly but with a filename using a cell value available in the excel file. Im jus unable to save the file with the filename as wanted.

Comment: Ok. Basically the idea is to save the subject line and recd time of the email in a worksheet of the macro workbook and merge both of these info to form a "filename". if i run this code as it is, it saves the above mentioned info to the macro WB and it also saves outlook attachments to the given local path. But im unable to use the "merged Filename" to the outlook attachment when it is saved to the local path. Instead it gets saved in the display name rather than the merged one. I tried to google for this particular method but ended unsuccessful. Any support would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, iterating over all items in an Outlook folder is not realy a good idea. Use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class instead. So, instead of the following code:

```
For Each OlMail In OlItems

     If OlMail.UnRead = False Then
```

Use this:

```
Private Sub FindAllUnreadEmails(folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

    Dim searchCriteria As String = "[UnRead] = true"
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim mail As Outlook._MailItem = Nothing
    Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim resultItem As Object = Nothing
   
        If (folder.UnReadItemCount > 0) Then
            
            folderItems = folder.Items
            resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria)
            While Not IsNothing(resultItem)
                If (TypeOf (resultItem) Is Outlook._MailItem) Then
                    counter += 1
                    mail = resultItem
                    Debug.Print("#" + counter.ToString() + _
                                          " - Subject: " + mail.Subject)
                End If
                resultItem = folderItems.FindNext()
            End While
            
        Else
            Debug.Print("There is no match in the " + _
                                   folder.Name + " folder.")
        End If
End Sub
```

Note, attached files can have the same file name. So, to uniquelly identify files I'd suggest introducing any IDs in the file name when attachments are saved to the disk.

Finally, to save the attached file with a workbook's content name you need to pass a cell value to the `SaveAsFile` method:

```
OlMail.attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFolder & "\" & yourWorksheet.Range("B2").Value
```

Comment: Hurray!!!
Works perfectly Thank u so much.....